# Is there how to validate into rich:calendar if the date selected is before a specific date?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have this component:

```
<rich:calendar enableManualInput="true" value="#{home.born}" datePattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
```

and i need to validate if the selected date is equal or before actual date at the momment...
Is there how to do it only with rich:calendar or i must verify it into home?

Problem solved! i've used the solution provided by Balusc.
Thanks everybody! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To validate it on the server side, you can use a `Validator`.

```
<rich:calendar ...>
    <f:validator validatorId="notAfterToday" />
</rich:calendar>
```

with

```
@FacesValidator("notAfterToday")
public class NotAfterTodayValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        Date date = (Date) value;
        Date today = new Date();

        if (date.after(today)) {
            String message = "Date may not be later than today.";
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(message));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This only performs client-side validation when selecting a date using the calendar icon. Typing in a date bypasses client-side validation.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do that using JavaScript (so on client side). If you look on the [Client API doc](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/calendar.jsf?tab=api), you can see that there is a `getCurrentDate()` JavaScript function provided by the rich:calendar component.

So what you have to do is to launch a JavaScript function on the JavaScript events `ondateselected` and `oninputchange` that will use the `getCurrentDate()` method and compare to the current date.

Something like that (I didn't test):

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    ...
    <rich:calendar id="myCalendar" enableManualInput="true" value="#{home.born}" datePattern="dd/MM/yyyy"
        ondateselected="checkDate();" oninputchange="checkDate();"/>
    ...
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkDate() {
    var choosenDate = $("myForm:myCalendar").component.getCurrentDate();
    var now = new Date();
    // Calculate the difference between the 2 dates.
    // This method may be modified if you want to only compare date (i.e. not time).
    var diff = choosenDate.getTime() - now.getTime();
    if (diff < 0) {
        // choosenDate is before today
        alert("Error in the selected date!");
        // Do what you want here...
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, but do I do to keep the date unchanged? Like if it's not a valid date and I want to keep the old value, what should I do next the validation?